# BOSCH mini split indoor fan keeps running after heating ends

Tags: hvac

For mini split units, isn't  the indoor fan supposed to stop after reaching the set temperature in heating mode? We've just installed two multi-zone Bosch mini splits and in heating mode after reaching the set point, the outdoor unit stops, but indoor unit fan keeps running and circulates the air ( which is almost cold because the compressor is off). After a while when temperature drops and outdoor units kick in, then there's warm air coming out of the indoor unit.

We tried to contact the manufacturer but did not getting a solid answer and just told us it's normal and if you don't want it turn the indoor unit off, but this does not make sense, how about during the night when we sleep?

Comment: Most fans for heating units have two selections.  One is auto which is suppose to run the fan for a bit after the heat turns off, maybe a minute or two.  The second is manual and the fan is on all the time.  Check to make sure your is on auto, if so then there is a problem/error.

Comment: what is your thermostat model

Comment: Do you have the fan set to a particular speed, or is it running "auto-speed?" Don't know about Bosch's setup, but for Mitsubishi if ou are on auto-speed the occasional "check the temperature" hunting is on lowest speed and does not cause any noticeable draft. If you set the fan manually to a higher speed that will apply.